# Call to undefined function bzdecompress PHP

Tags: nginx, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-16.04, php-7, bzip2

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with PHP7 + nginx running. I already have a project in PHP Laravel 5.1 running in my local enviroment (Windows with Xampp) and everything is running great.
I have a PHP script that uses the function `bzdecompress` of `Bzip2` but then, in the server just crash and show this message:

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\bzdecompress()
```

I don't see instructions of how install this library (if needed) or how to load it or check at least that is loaded. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1)** check your installed packages `php -m`

if bzip2 is installed move to step **3** directly , if not installed then install it by running :

**2)** for php7 :

```
apt-get install php7.0-bz2
```

for php5:

```
apt-get install php-bz2
```

**3)** then make sure that you've enabled your extension via :

```
phpenmod bz2
```

**4)** then you can restart your server

```
service nginx restart
```